# Is it possible to use seq2Seq models to predict HTML code from XML file?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoders, embeddings, seq2seq

I have XML file that describes some embedded components. So the file has different markups that correspond to different fields. The intention behind this project is to generate automatically UI descriptive layouts for those XML files. I saw the seq2seq model [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/#basic). I was wondering if I can use the same architecture (Encoder-Decoder) to generate HTML files that describe the content of the fields in the XML file.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen any examples to predict code using encoder-decoder methods (but you probably can!). However, "[The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)" by Andrej Karpathy outlines how RNN models can be used to generate source code for $\LaTeX$ documents and the Linux kernel, so that method should be just as effective at the HTML/XML task.

Comment: Thank you for sharing such important article with me. I will definitely try the RNN models and give you my feedback. It will take me some time I guess.